# Property 'body' does not exist on type 'Observable<Object>'. Angular.js Discord OAuth2

Tags: angularjs, typescript, discord

Im making a Discord Bot Dashboard and implementing Discord OAuth2. I'm following the guide here: https://discordjs.guide/oauth2/#a-quick-example and the code is essentially the same.

```
async getJSONResponse(body) {
    let fullBody = '';

    for await(const data of body) {
      fullBody += data.toString();
    }

    return JSON.parse(fullBody)
  }

  async getAccessToken(code) {
    if (code) {
      try {
        let body = new URLSearchParams();
        body.append('client_id', environment.discord.clientId)
        body.append('client_secret', environment.discord.clientSecret)
        body.append('code', code)
        body.append('grant_type', 'authorization_code')
        body.append('redirect_uri', environment.discord.redirect)
        body.append('scope', 'identify')

        let options = {
          headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
        };

        const tokenResponseData = await this.http.post('https://discord.com/api/oauth2/token', body.toString(), options)
  
        const oauthData = await this.getJSONResponse(tokenResponseData.body)
        console.log(oauthData)

      } catch(err) {
        console.error('an error')
        console.error(err)
      }
    }
  }
```

However, I get this error: `Property 'body' does not exist on type 'Observable<Object>'.`
As you can see, the guide above clearly shows that `body` does in fact exist on the object.

I'm out of ideas, any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RxJs get value from observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37607257/rxjs-get-value-from-observable)

Comment: @TobiasS. No, still same error