# How can we create an Object from an Observable<Object> in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I want to send the object returned to my service with `serviceName.setObject(myObject: object)` for example so I can call that object from a different component, and use it to display some of it's data. In other words, I want to get a Character Object when the user selects it in a `NameComponent` so I can call it my `StatisticsComponent`, where I display the statistics of the Character like so `{{ myCharacter.name }}` for example. I'm still new to Angular and I thought I'd find the answer easily with a bit of research, but it doesn't seem to be the case.

As of my latest attempt, I am able to get an Observable of my Object and send all the data I need to the console log with the method down below :

```
this.myService.getAllInfosById(this.getPersonnageIdByName(change))
   .subscribe(response => {
       console.log("All Details of Personnage", response);
   });
```

And I'm pretty sure the subscribe is what I need to update, but I'd need help from you guys on this one. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you want to do with the `response` object?

Comment: I clarified my question, thank you

Comment: Can you show more of your code? Which component has the service call?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RxJs get value from observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37607257/rxjs-get-value-from-observable)

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't pretty much clear but I think you might looking for [Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html)

**Example**

```
getAllInfosById<Type>(arg: Type): Observable<Type> {
  return of(arg);
}
```

Usage

```
this.myService.getAllInfosById<Personnage>(this.getPersonnageIdByName(change))
  .subscribe(response => {
  console.log("All Details of Personnage", response);
});
```

Example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v12-h2hfpd?file=src/app/app.component.ts)