# Getting the value of an observable

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to Typescript/Angular so please bear with me if this has been asked already (I couldn't find it anywhere) or is a very simple answer :)

I need to display a timer on my page.  I have created it in my component like this:

```
this.secondsRemaining$ = timer(0, 1000).pipe(
      map(n => 30 - n),
      takeWhile(n => n >= 0 && someCondition))
);
```

I display the timer on my page like this:

```
{{ secondsRemaining$ | async }}
```

When `someCondition` is false, the timer will stop.  I then need to get the value at which the timer stopped, but I'm unsure how.  Is this possible?  Do I need to use something other than an Observable (like BehaviorSubject)?

Comment: Where do you need to get the value of `secondsRemaining$` ? Your code will display values from `30` to `1` on you page and stop when `someCondition` is `false`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RxJs get value from observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37607257/rxjs-get-value-from-observable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could tap and save it to a local property, in this example named `secondsRemaining`:

```js
this.secondsRemaining$ = timer(0, 1000).pipe(
      map(n => 30 - n),
      takeWhile(n => n >= 0 && someCondition),
      tap(n => this.secondsRemaining = n)
  )
);
```